# how many positive integers solutions of $abc+3ab+2ac+bc+6a+3b+2c = 210$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem about the number of positive integers solutions.

$abc+3ab+2ac+bc+6a+3b+2c = 210$

I rewrote it to   $(a+1)(b+2)(c+3)=216$

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer%20solution%20of%20%28x%2B1%29%28y%20%2B2%29%28z%20%2B3%29%3D216)  ,  there are 16 positive integers solutions.

but $a=11 , b=1 , c=3$ is also true!!!

Why does $a=11, b=1 , c=3$ not appear on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer%20solution%20of%20%28x%2B1%29%28y%20%2B2%29%28z%20%2B3%29%3D216).I'm so confused.

Thank you in advance for every comments.

Comment: Click the **more solutions** button

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici pressed more solution button and  still not have a=11 , b=1 ,c=3   , wolfram cannot display remaining solutions?

Comment: May be it is running out of time.

Comment: Type **integer solution of (x+1)(y +2)(z +3)=216 , x>0 ,y>0 ,z>0**

Answer (score 0):

Adding $6$ to both sides of the equation, we get $abc+3ab+2ac+bc+6a+3b+2c+6=(a+1)(b+2)(c+3)=216.$

Now, one just has to compare factors and see which makes sense (e.g. $216=2\cdot3\cdot36$, so $(a,b,c)=(1,1,33)$ is one solution.)